# Virus scan shows 6 chaindata files infected, when quarantined, node can't be found

Tags: ethereumj

3+3 backups but when left alone ETH runs fine v0-8-1, tried to redownload same problem, what to do? Description=ANAPHYLAXSIS

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a false positive. The best thing to do is to just whitelist the Ethereum folder.

Comment: thanks, me thinks this imac and scanner are not ready for blockchaindata... running el-capitan 10.11.5

Comment: Because Ethereum uses a lot of data and resources, and has lots of P2P libraries and other suspicious-looking code, it is often mistaken for a virus. Lots of malware interacts with p2p networks nowadays, so scanners tend to overreact to blockchain nodes.